# Detail Disclosure Button on MapView Callout will not respond to tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I would like to have another view loaded when I tap on the disclosure button in my map callout.

I added the button to the callout using the following in the initWithAnnotation method of my AnnotationView implementation file (I am only showing the relevant code):

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier

{

 self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

}
```

I also added the following controllTapped method to my MapViewController implementation file for detecting when the disclosure button has been tapped:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

{

    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];



}
```

I also created a new detailedDisclosure class with an .XIB for a UI.  This is the view I want to load when the user taps the disclosure button.

Why, then, does nothing happen when the user taps the disclosure button?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *btnGo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[btnGo addTarget:self action:@selector(goToLocation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView=btnGo;


-(void) goToLocation:(UIButton *) sender
{
}
```

Comment: Are you saying to replace the current disclosurebutton syntax I have with this?  In the (id)initWithAnnotation....method? Also, what would go in the goToLocation brackets?  The pushViewController syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `MKMapView` delegate method for this purpose like following, for identifying your `CustomAnnotationClass`:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [view annotation];
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotationClass class]])
    {
        DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Let me kno, If you get it to work.

Comment: Still nothing happens.  If I set the breakpoint I can see that the program DOES enter the IF statement.  It seems that the pushViewController doesn't do anything.  Could I be missing some kind of connection to my detailViewController? Does it need some action method and/or outlet to go along the DisclosureButton? Or does the controlTapped method need to be declared in the header file?

Comment: If it DOES get into the IF statement, then your problem is only to find out WHY detailViewController is not getting pushed. You can try `DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];`